# how to show multiple polls for this poll script?

Tags: html, ajax, http

I'm trying to get two polls showing on the same page for this [Smart PHP Poll](http://www.scriptsez.net/?action=details&cat=Polls%20and%20Voting&id=2195726297).

I got it to show both polls by making the requests synchronous but now whenever i click on show results for the first poll, the results of the second one show up instead of the first. 
I try to daisychain the divID along but i seem to be going wrong somewhere, as it ends up just showing "Please Wait" instead of showing the results.

**html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script> // in head
<div class ="poll-container">

    <div class ="my-poll">
    <div id="text"></div>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    getpoll('1377511990', 'text');
    </SCRIPT>
    </div>

    <div class ="my-poll">
    <div id="text2"></div>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    getpoll('1377513905', 'text2');
    </SCRIPT>
    </div>


</div>
```

**ajax script**

```
function createRequestObject() {
    var req;


    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
    alert('Problem creating the XMLHttpRequest object');
    }
    return req;
    }
    var http = createRequestObject();

    http.ontimeout = function () {
        console.error("The request for " + url + " timed out.");
      };

    function getpoll(pID, divID) {
    var xmlhttp = http;
    xmlhttp.open('post', 'fetch.php?action=showpoll&id='+pid, false);
//  xmlhttp.open('post', 'fetch.php?action=showpoll&id='+pid+'&divID='+divID, false);
    document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = "Please wait";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    }

    function begen(j){
    window.self.document.getElementById("option").value=j;
    }

    function fetch(){
    var xmlhttp = http;
    var op=encodeURI(document.getElementById("option").value);
    xmlhttp.open('post', 'fetch.php?action=post_result&id='+pid+'&option='+op, false);
  //  xmlhttp.open('post', 'fetch.php?action=post_result&id='+pid+'&option='+op+'&divID='+divID, false);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
   // xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleResponse(divID);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    }


    function result(){
    var xmlhttp = http;
    xmlhttp.open('post', 'fetch.php?action=see_result&id='+pid, false);
  //  xmlhttp.open('post', 'fetch.php?action=see_result&id='+pid+'&divID='+divID, false);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
   // xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleResponse(divID);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    }


    function handleResponse() {
    var xmlhttp = http;
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
    var response = http.responseText;
        if(response) {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = response;
        //document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML = response;
        }
    }
    }
```

**fetch.php**

```
<?php
foreach($_GET AS $key => $value) {
${$key} = $value;
} 
foreach($_POST AS $key => $value) {
${$key} = $value;
} 
include ("conf.php");   // database details.

$db=mysql_connect($db_host,$database_user,$database_pass) or 
die("<b>MySQL Error:</b> Unable to connect to database please check that you have provided the correct 
    <li>Database Login username<li>Database Login Password");   

//Connect to database or give error if failed
mysql_select_db($db_name,$db)or 
die("<b>MySQL Error:</b> Unable to select database please check that you have provided the correct <li>Database name");



// start showpoll action

if($action=="showpoll" && $id!="" && $divID !=""){
    $mpi=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smp_cust");
    $col=mysql_fetch_array($mpi);
    $pc=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smp_quiz WHERE tm='$id'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($pc)==1){
        $now=mysql_fetch_array($pc);

        echo "<form onsubmit=\"javascript: return false;\"><table width=\"$col[pw]\"  style='border:$col[boc] 1px solid;' 
            cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 bgcolor=\"$col[bbc]\"><TR bgcolor=\"$col[hlc]\" 
                height=\"25\"><TD style='padding:4px;font-size:$col[hls]px;color:$col[ttc];' 
                valign=middle><B>$now[title]</B></TD></TR><TR height=10><td>
                    <img src='images/space.gif' height=1 width=1></td></TR>";

        $nx=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smp_answer WHERE tm='$id'");

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($nx)){
            echo "<TR height=\"25\"><td style='padding:2px;font:$col[bts]px verdana, tahoma; color:$col[btc]; 
                text-align:left;' valign=top><input type=radio name=note value=\"$row[qid]\" 
                onclick=\"begen($row[qid]);\"> $row[answer]</td></TR>";
        }

        echo "<input type=hidden name=\"option\" id=\"option\" value=\"\">";
        echo "<TR height=\"25\"><TD align=\"center\">
                <input type=\"submit\" 
                onclick=\"javascript:fetch($id , $divID);\" style='color:$col[buc]' value=\"Submit\"><BR><BR>
                <a href=\"#showr\" onclick=\"javascript:result($id, $divID);\">
                <font size='1' color=\"$col[btc]\">See Results</a></font>
                </TD></TR><TR height=10><td><img src='images/space.gif' height=1 width=1></td></TR>
                </Table><BR><table border=0 cellspacing=0 width=\"$col[pw]\">
                <TR height=\"25\">
                <td width='100%' style='padding:2px;font:10px verdana, tahoma; color:#330000; text-align:right;' 
                valign=top></a></TD></TR>
                </table>";
        echo "</form>";
    }else{
        //echo "<table border=0 cellspacing=0 width=\"$col[pw]\"><TR height=\"25\">
        //<td width='100%' style='padding:2px;font:10px verdana, tahoma; color:#330000; text-align:center;' 
        //valign=top>This poll has been deleted.</td></TR><TR height=\"25\"><td width='100%' 
        //style='padding:2px;font:10px verdana, tahoma; color:#330000; text-align:center;' 
        //valign=top>Powered By: <a href=\"http://www.scriptsez.net\" target=\"_blank\">
        //<font size='1' color='#330000'>Smart PHP Poll</a></TD></TR></table>";
    }
} // end showpoll action


// start post_result action

if($action=="post_result" && $id!=""){
$ip=getenv('remote_addr');
//$ip=rand(1,1000);
$option=trim($option);
$mpi=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smp_cust");
$col=mysql_fetch_array($mpi);
$pc=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smp_quiz WHERE tm='$id'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($pc)==1){
        $now=mysql_fetch_array($pc);

        echo "<table width=\"$col[pw]\" style='border:$col[boc] 1px solid;' cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 
        bgcolor=\"$col[bbc]\"><TR bgcolor=\"$col[hlc]\" height=\"25\">
            <TD style='padding:4px;font-size:$col[hls]px;color:$col[ttc];' valign=middle><B>$now[title]</B>
            </TD></TR><TR height=10><td><img src='images/space.gif' height=1 width=1></td></TR>";

        $prog=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smp_result WHERE tm='$id' AND ip='$ip'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($prog)>0){
        echo "<TR height=\"25\"><td style='padding:2px;font:$col[bts]px verdana, tahoma; color:$col[btc]; 
            text-align:left;' valign=top><b>You have already voted</b></td></TR>";
        }else{
            if($option!=""){
            $ins=mysql_query("INSERT INTO smp_result SET point='$option',ip='$ip', tm='$id'");
            }else{
            echo "<TR height=\"25\"><td style='padding:2px;font:$col[bts]px verdana, tahoma; color:$col[btc];
                text-align:left;' valign=top><b>Please select an option.</b></td></TR>";
            }
        }

        $nx=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smp_answer WHERE tm='$id'");
        $total_results=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smp_result WHERE tm='$id'");
        $total_re=mysql_num_rows($total_results);

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($nx)){
            $opt=$row['qid'];
            $prong=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smp_result WHERE tm='$id' AND point='$row[qid]'");
            $tse=mysql_num_rows($prong);
            $result[$opt]=$tse;

            if($total_re>0){
                $percentage=round(($tse/$total_re)*100,2);
            }else{
                $percentage=0;
            }

            $wt=100-$percentage;

            if($percentage==0){
                $tdw=1;
            }else{
                $tdw=$percentage;
            }

            echo "<TR height=\"18\"><td style='padding:2px;font:$col[bts]px verdana, tahoma; 
                color:$col[btc]; text-align:left;' valign=top>$row[answer]</td></TR>";
            echo "<TR height=\"18\"><td style=\"padding-left:2px;\">
                <table width=\"80%\" align=left cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr height=\"10\">
                <td bgcolor=\"$col[hlc]\" width=\"$tdw%\"><img src=\"images/spacer.gif\" 
                width=\"0\" height=\"1\"></td><td width=\"$wt\"  
                    style=\"font:$col[bts]px verdana, tahoma;
                color:$col[btc]; text-align:left;\">
                <img src=\"images/spacer.gif\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\">$percentage%</td>
                    </tr></table></td></TR>";
            echo "<tr height=\"10\"><td width=100%><img src=\"images/spacer.gif\" width=\"1\" 
                height=\"1\"></td></tr>";
        }

        echo "<tr height=\"5\"><td width=100%>
            <img src=\"images/spacer.gif\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\"></td></tr>";

        echo "<TR height=\"18\"><td style='padding:2px;font:$col[bts]px verdana, tahoma; color:$col[btc]; 
            text-align:left;' valign=top>Total Votes: $total_re</td></TR>";
        //echo "<TR height=10><td><img src='images/space.gif' height=1 width=1></td>
        //</TR></Table><BR><table border=0 cellspacing=0 width=\"$col[pw]\"><TR height=\"25\">
        //<td width='100%' style='padding:2px;font:10px verdana, tahoma; color:#330000; text-align:right;' 
        //valign=top>Powered By: <a href=\"http://www.scriptsez.net\" target=\"_blank\">
        //<font size='1' color='#330000'>Smart PHP Poll</a></TD></TR></table>";
    }
}// end action post_result


// start action see_result

if($action=="see_result" && $id!=""){
    //$option=trim($option);
    $mpi=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smp_cust");
    $col=mysql_fetch_array($mpi);
    $pc=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smp_quiz WHERE tm='$id'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($pc)==1){
        $now=mysql_fetch_array($pc);
        echo "<table width=\"$col[pw]\" style='border:$col[boc] 1px solid;' 
            cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 bgcolor=\"$col[bbc]\"><TR bgcolor=\"$col[hlc]\" 
            height=\"25\"><TD style='padding:4px;font-size:$col[hls]px;color:$col[ttc];' 
            valign=middle><B>$now[title]</B></TD></TR><TR height=10><td>
            <img src='images/space.gif' height=1 width=1></td></TR>";

        $nx=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smp_answer WHERE tm='$id'");
        $total_results=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smp_result WHERE tm='$id'");
        $total_re=mysql_num_rows($total_results);

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($nx)){
            $opt=$row['qid'];
            $prong=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smp_result WHERE tm='$id' AND point='$row[qid]'");
            $tse=mysql_num_rows($prong);
            $result[$opt]=$tse;

            if($total_re>0){
                $percentage=round(($tse/$total_re)*100,2);
            }else{
                $percentage=0;
            }
            if($percentage==0){
                $tdw=1;
            }else{
                $tdw=$percentage;
            }
            $wt=100-$percentage;
            echo "<TR height=\"18\"><td style='padding:2px;font:$col[bts]px verdana, tahoma; 
                color:$col[btc]; text-align:left;' valign=top>$row[answer]</td></TR>";
            echo "<TR height=\"18\"><td style=\"padding-left:2px;\"><table width=\"80%\" 
                align=left cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr height=\"10\"><td bgcolor=\"$col[hlc]\"
                width=\"$tdw%\"><img src=\"images/spacer.gif\" width=\"0\" height=\"1\">
                </td><td width=\"$wt\" style=\"font:$col[bts]px verdana, tahoma; color:$col[btc]; 
                text-align:left;\"><img src=\"images/spacer.gif\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\">$percentage%
                </td></tr></table></td></TR>";
            echo "<tr height=\"10\"><td width=100%><img src=\"images/spacer.gif\" 
                width=\"1\" height=\"1\"></td></tr>";
        }
        echo "<tr height=\"5\"><td width=100%><img src=\"images/spacer.gif\" width=\"1\" 
            height=\"1\"></td></tr>";
        echo "<TR height=\"18\"><td style='padding:2px;font:$col[bts]px verdana, tahoma; color:$col[btc];
            text-align:left;' valign=top>Total Votes: $total_re</td></TR>";
        //echo "<TR height=10><td><img src='images/space.gif' height=1 width=1></td></TR>
        //</Table><BR><table border=0 cellspacing=0 width=\"$col[pw]\"><TR height=\"25\">
        //<td width='100%' style='padding:2px;font:10px verdana, tahoma; color:#330000; text-align:right;' 
        //valign=top>Powered By: <a href=\"http://www.scriptsez.net\" target=\"_blank\">
        //<font size='1' color='#330000'>Smart PHP Poll</a></TD></TR></table>";
    }
}// end action see_result

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //error:
    document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML = "Please wait";

    //correct:
    function getpoll(pID, divID) 
    {
        var xmlhttp = http;
        xmlhttp.open('post', 'fetch.php?action=showpoll&id='+pid, false);
        document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML = "Please wait";
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleResponse(divID);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }


    function handleResponse(divID='text') 
    {
        var xmlhttp = http;
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            var response = http.responseText;
            if(response) 
            {
                document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML = response;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to this please?

Comment: basically, keep the variable 'divID' for later use.

handleResponse funtion in defined "divID= text" just comes empty.